# Combine two SQL queries which use Date Intervals, Group and SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

First off, thank you in advance.

I have 2 queries that I am working with as I would like to compare last week to the previous week...

Getting Last Week

```
SELECT keyword,
    SUM(users_desktop) AS desktop_last_week
FROM js 
    WHERE country='US' 
    AND  day >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY 
    AND day < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY 
GROUP BY keyword
ORDER BY desktop_last_week DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Getting Previous Week

```
SELECT keyword,
    SUM(users_desktop) AS desktop_previous_week
FROM js 
    WHERE country='US' 
    AND  day >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+12 DAY 
    AND day < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-7 DAY 
GROUP BY keyword
ORDER BY desktop_previous_week DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

What I would like to do is combine these queries so that I can then ORDER BY the division of desktop_last_week/desktop_this_week to find keywords that are trending up (ie: searched a lot more this week than last week)

Any idea on how to combine these together?

Comment: Do you want 10 records from each week? Do a UNION ALL.

Comment: First off, welcome to SO. Now see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called conditional aggregation. Use `where` clauses from your existing queries to do it.

```
SELECT keyword, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN day >= Curdate() - INTERVAL Dayofweek(Curdate())+6 day 
                  AND day < Curdate() - INTERVAL Dayofweek(Curdate())-1 day THEN 
             users_desktop 
             ELSE 0 
           end) AS desktop_last_week, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN day >= Curdate() - INTERVAL Dayofweek(Curdate())+12 day 
                  AND day < Curdate() - INTERVAL Dayofweek(Curdate())-7 day THEN 
             users_desktop 
             ELSE 0 
           end) AS desktop_prev_last_week 
FROM   js 
WHERE  country = 'US' 
GROUP  BY keyword 
ORDER  BY desktop_prev_last_week / desktop_this_week DESC 
LIMIT  10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Union!
You can get 2 Queries to one with that. If you want to order that then put it into a subquery

Answer (score 0):

You could expand the `where` clause to contain both time ranges and move the logic of differentiating between them to `case` expressions inside the sums. By the way, using the `between` operator instead of a >= and < pair would make the query itself a tad easier to read:

```
SELECT    keyword,
          SUM(CASE WHEN day BETWEEN 
                        (CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 6 DAY) AND
                        (CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) - 1 DAY) 
                    THEN users_desktop 
               END) AS desktop_last_week,
          SUM(CASE WHEN day BETWEEN 
                        (CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 12 DAY) AND
                        (CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) - 7 DAY) 
                    THEN users_desktop 
               END) AS desktop_previous_week
FROM     js 
WHERE    country = 'US' 
GROUP BY keyword
ORDER BY desktop_last_week DESC, desktop_previous_week DESC
LIMIT    10;
```